# Retrieval of contacts from gmail

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6

Good day. How do i retrieve/send contacts from my gmail, to my android device. The con acts were not saved on my phone or SIM card, only on the gmail account.
Please help.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can sync your gmail contacts to your S6 like this:

Go to:

1. Settings
2. Accounts
3. Google
4. Click on your account name
5. Toggle Sync Contacts On
6. On upper right corner select More
7. Select Sync Now

---

You can use as alternative to only show your gmail contacts not store them on the phone like this:

Go to:

1. Contacts
2. Upper right side select More
3. Settings
4. Select Contacts to display
5. Select your google account (or select the first option but this will show you all contacts from all accounts / or select customized list and edit witch account should show what)

Comment: Thanx for the response.  I tried both these methods before I posted my question and neither of them work. I thought that it was perhaps because my contacts were not stored on my S6 or on my SIM. However, when my cell service provider did a remote access test on my phone (we downloaded a link that gave them access to my S6) we added her account to my phone and her contacts immediately were added to my contacts list, even though her contacts had never been saved on my S6 or my SIM before. This led us to believe that it must be a setting on my gmail account .